# I can log in everywhere with an e-mail address no longer tied to my account

Tags: support, login

A couple of minutes ago I discovered this by accident. So in short, I can log in on very Stack Exchange site with an e-mail id which is no longer associated with this account. The current e-mail address that is set works fine too of course.

Comment: When you say "invalid", what do you mean? "turtles"? "alsdfjalsdkfjalsj320430@bogus.domain"? "me@example.com"? A valid email address that you didn't think you had on your account?

Comment: (you may want to [contact support](/contact) about this, as I'm reluctant to post details here - but as far as I can tell, you signed up years ago with an email that was associated with both Facebook and SE OpenID credentials, then removed the email and Facebook login but left the SE login intact - this then allowed you to continue logging in with that email + a password. But... If you're talking about something else... Get in touch privately, please!)

Comment: no, it is a valid email address with a valid domain, like example@yahoo.com which i still use it but not anymore to login on stack because as I said, i've changet it to something else like example@gmail.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, I think I know what's going on...

You get one "contact" email, which you can change here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/email/settings/current - but you can have unlimited login emails, which you can view (and change) here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current - you've changed the former, but the latter remain.

These are *slightly* linked, in that if you have a verified contact email you can create a credential for it at any time simply by resetting your password - so it *will* in effect act as a credential by itself. This is mostly a convenience, a way to help folks avoid getting locked out of their accounts: generally you would not want a contact email that isn't also a credential. However, some folks do, and the system does allow it.

Comment: well that was it, weird though in some way.